# Como montar grid em Bootstrap 3 para imagens pequenas

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando adaptar um grid em `Bootstrap 3` para imagens pequenas com possibilidade da página ser responsiva, essas imagens são inseridas via formulário como `.png` e enviadas para `banco de dados` e em uma pasta específica em minha hospedagem, mas a adaptação do que tenho não está ficando como deveria, montei um grid com uma opção que consegui, o que fiz foi isso:

[Página de Thumbs](http://ancestofados.com.br/anc/modelo3.php)

E o que realmente preciso é isso:

[Página Modelo](http://ancestofados.com.br/anc/cores.php)

Por mais que tente as alterações não surtem efeito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu problema ocorre pois o bootstrap possui um limite de grid de 12 colunas. Ou seja, você não vai conseguir mais do que isso utilizando o grid do bootstrap.

Uma solução seria usar um calc para fazer essa divisão. Digamos que você queira 20 thumbnails em uma mesma linha, você pode usar da seguinte maneira:

```
<div class="minhalista">
    <div class="thumb">00</div>
    //[.. repita suas thumbs ..]
</div>
```

E no css:

```
.thumb {
    display:inline-block;
    width: calc(100%/20);
}
```

Deste modo, sua largura total seria dividida de modo igual por 20 colunas.
Veja este exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/c0nxhjwz/

Importante: Note que esse tipo de layout pode ficar complexo ou não funcionar corretamente em screen menores. Apenas tome cuidado com isso.

Comment: Olá @CelsomTrindade, obrigado pela excelente dica, realmente perfeito, me ajudou muito.

Comment: @adventistapr não por isso! Se a resposta resolveu seu problema, não esqueça de marcar como resolvido. =D